# Invalid object name 'dbo.customers1'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, ef-database-first

I'm getting the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.customers1'" on my view...

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.orderid</td>
            <td>@item.customer.firstname</td>
```

I have the ViewModel classes...

```
public class orders
{
    [Key]
    public int orderid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime createdate { get; set; }
    public string createdby { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> statusid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> pickup { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dropoff { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> scheduledout { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> scheduledin { get; set; }
    public bool instorepickup { get; set; }
    public string paymenttype { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime reservationstart { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime reservationend { get; set; }
    public bool morningpickup { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> customerid { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string shippingtype { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> shippingestimate { get; set; }

    public virtual customer customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<invoice> invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual orderstatuses orderstatuses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<serialorders> serialorders { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class customers
{
    [Key]
    public int customerid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime createdate { get; set; }

    public string firstname { get; set; }

    public string lastname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string billingaddress1 { get; set; }
    public string billingaddress2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string billingcity { get; set; }
    public string billingstate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string billingzip { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string billingcountry { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string shippingaddress1 { get; set; }
    public string shippingaddress2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string shippingcity { get; set; }
    public string shippingstate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string shippingzip { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string shippingcountry { get; set; }
    public bool goodstanding { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> insuranceexp { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<invoice> invoices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
}
```

this is my model...

[image: EF data model]

And I have a data access layer...

```
public DbSet<tvc.viewModels.orders> orders { get; set; }
public DbSet<tvc.viewModels.customers> customers { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight-forward. There's no `dbo.customers1` table in your database. As to why, there's really not enough information here to say, but the most likely causes are:

1. You're using Database First or Code First with an existing database, and your entities are out of sync with the database.
2. You're using Code First, don't have migrations enabled, and you've made a change to either your entities or your database. Again, out of sync.
3. You've specified an explicit table name, either via the `Table` attribute or fluent config, that doesn't exist. Either way, change either the explicit table name to what it should be or rename your database table so it matches.

Comment: Its database first and the model is synced with the db. I don't know why its looking for customers1 - I assume its related to conventions and mvc is appending the 1? I would think I have a relationship set up incorrectly in the db or in the viewmodel, but I've shown everything in my question...

Comment: Welcome to the joys of EDMX. For what it's worth, you can use Code First with an existing database, which is actually preferred at this point, since EDMX is deprecated (see: http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/). If you want to stick with EDMX, I'd recommend just regenerating it from your database. That should fix whatever issue there is.

Answer (score 0):

There was an oversight in my ViewModel. I was pointing customer, which is the name of the database table and the model class, rather than the viewmodel class which is customers (with an s).